# Animate scroll 100% (horizontal)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my page (apolloedge.com/beta/port.html), I have 2 buttons: one that I want to scroll left `onclick` and one that I want to scroll right `onclick`, respectively.  The container element has the id of `#header2`.  The child element has a class of `.showc`.  This element (`.showc`) has a width of 100%.  How can I make it so that the buttons scroll 100% (animated) `onclick` using JavaScript and/or jQuery?  Thanks a bunch for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a library called Cycle2. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 `transition` property to animate the image containers like so:

```css
.showc {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out; 
}
```

Then your left or right directional `onclick` handler change the `margin-left` value of the first `.showc`.